Export chatbox Using API or Meta business suite
I have a question about this. Is it possible to export chatbox conversations from Facebook using some API? I have a page and I need to do something like sentiment analysis, but I need the conversations from the chatbox. Is there any way to export these conversations? I also have Meta Business Suite.
